# CreateProcess of console app, and get the main window handled

Tags: winapi, createprocess

I am trying to write a program what will manage few console windows, my program will be able to `CreateProcess()` for new console windows, get a window main handle and the use that handle to resize, close, hide, change title etc. But I cannot find a reliable way to get a main window handle. The purpose is to have a tab bar and switch between created console windows with the click on the tab.

I have tried few ways:

1) use windows `"cmd.exe"` ability to set window title, and then `FindWindow("tmp_title"...)`
This has a problem, I do not need `cmd.exe` running, and also I need a `processID` for the target program not the `cmd.exe`. Maybe I should use this way but check for children subprocesses?

2) `EnumWindows()` then `CreateProcess()` then wait 40 ms, then `EnumWindows()` again and find the new window.
This is unreliable! I got two new windows sometimes for weird reasons.

3) use `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` + `EnumWindows()`. This worked the best on XP, but on win7 the found window seems to be the wrong one, it's `GetWindowText()` returns `"DefaultIME"` and hide/show of this window does nothing. So it is obviously a wrong one.

So any idea how to do it reliably and if possible cross-platform (Cross-windows, XP,Vista,7)

Comment: This is a bad idea.  Even if you get a valid window handle then there's still little you can do with it.  This is an XY question, we can't see the X.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Are you asking the purpose of the program I am writing? I will update the question.

Comment: From your description, it sounds like you want to embed the console windows inside your tabbed window. That will not work. You cannot create a cross-process window hierarchy without careful coordination between the two processes, and the console window is definitely not aware of the wacky things you're doing.

Comment: No, I am not going to put it inside my own window. Just hide/show, change title, maybe change position.

Comment: I think the most reliable method might be injecting code to the newly created process and calling `GetConsoleWindow` from there.